# Error found in : A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-userprofile, farm-solution

I have experienced that SharePoint user profile custom search not working and I observed the issue(Farm solution and it used SharePoint 2019). Then I got this below error message

A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure Process

*Name: w3wp*

*Process ID: 12132*

*AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/SecurityTokenServiceApplication-1-133353879586016182*

*AppDomain ID: 2*

*Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:a6195aa3a5d845......24c0e9d9c249#authority=urn:uuid:407d09bac7fc......36dbbcde9e35df&authority=*

Application side I got this error as well : "ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData threw exception: Access is denied"

Any idea on this please help me. Thank you very much.